# Automator Quick Action (AppleScript) for Deepl Translator

Tags: macos, applescript, translation

I have an Automator quick action (service) to get texts from applications and open them on the Deepl website to translate them. It works, but the spaces between the words get replaced with + signs. The translation is filled with + signs, like this:

"...+in+third+place+on+the+list+of+the+most+..."

What is causing this?

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set output to "https://www.deepl.com/translator#pt/en/" & urldecode(input as string)
    return output
end run

on urldecode(x)
    set cmd to "'require \"cgi\"; puts CGI.escape(STDIN.read.chomp)'"
    do shell script "echo " & quoted form of x & " | ruby -e " & cmd
end urldecode
```

Comment: You need to encode _spaces_ as `%20` **not** `+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use '**Listing 32-7** AppleScriptObjC: Handler that URL encodes text' from [Encoding and Decoding Text](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/EncodeandDecodeText.html).

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

on run {input, parameters}
    set output to "https://www.deepl.com/translator#pt/en/" & encodeText(input as string)
    return output
end run

on encodeText(theText)
    set theString to stringWithString_(theText) of NSString of current application
    set theEncoding to NSUTF8StringEncoding of current application
    set theAdjustedString to stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding_(theEncoding) of theString
    return (theAdjustedString as string)
end encodeText
```